# Run script as another user without sudo/su privileges

Tags: ssh, sudo, setuid, su

I'm trying to write a script so that it can be called by one user and is executed as another user. I thought that setuid might be able to do this so I enabled setuid using chmod u+s with the owner of the script being user1. I call the script (which only contains whoami right now) as user2 and it still shows user2 instead of user1. How can I make this be user1.

-- My end result is I want one user to be able to call this script and have it ssh into another server and execute a command as another user.

Comment: Why do you have to execute the script as another user? Is it because you want to use that user's SSH key to log in to the server?

Comment: Exactly. Even being able to source that user's key and login as them would work.

Comment: Can't you just allow the actual user to log in to the server by adding his SSH key to the server user's authorized keys?

Comment: I would rather not considering I would have to push the key to 100+ servers.

Comment: Yeah, `setuid` has the script run with the *privileges* of the owner, but not their identity.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy that user's key (`id_rsa`) and pass it to `ssh` when connecting to the server:

```
ssh -i user1_id_rsa user1@server
```

However, this is rather a bad solution, security-wise. Adding the user's key to the authorized keys on the server, as I said in the comment, is the proper way to do it, and you should really look into that.

Comment: Right, but user2 doesn't normally have access to user1's keyfile.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a third user in your security model, who can run the program, but is otherwise unprivileged. This third user is an assumable identity for a number of users so they can run the process on the remote server.